# Plot different Times Series Data in one Chart with shared x-Axes Pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot 5 different data frames in 1 plot. Containing the same measurement but done at different times. The plot should share the x-Axis for all measurement.

First thing i did was to calculate the time between the measurement points. It differs between 5-10 ms but sometimes also big gaps of 200 ms.

Then i calculated the running sum over this column. Then i set this column as the index (dtype "timedelta64[ns]")

Now i want to plot those 5 times.series in one plot which share the x-Axis (as time in ms)

But i don´t now how because they have almost no common index together. The plot should have one common x-Axis from 0-3 seconds containing the 5 measurements.

Thank you!

2 Example DataFrames:
[example for measuremt01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaiLy.jpg)
[example for measuremt02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsfnA.jpg)

Comment: I do not see the problem. Just plot them in the same axes and you're done. `ax = df1.plot(); df2.plot(ax=ax)`. If there is a problem then, show the code you experience the problem with, see [mcve].

Comment: Wonderful! It worked. Thanks for your help